# Occasional `Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier` error

Tags: sql, sql-server, wcf, type-conversion, sqldependency

I am developing some `SqlDependency` and `Sql Notification` concepts for caching purposes on my wcf service this week. And in the meantime I have faced with a problem twice. And it constantly bugs my mind.

Occasionaly database starts to give the error of `Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier`. I am sure there isn't any wrong parameters, system has been working fine for more than 6 months. When this problem occurs all the tables containing a `uniqueidentifier` type column gives that error in case of any query made to them.

More annoyingly when I Stop and Start the MSSQL service, problem goes away.

What might be causing this behaviour on my DB?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your uniqueidentifier column/variable is having less precision and parameter cannot fit in, try increasing the precision. Or just make sure the parameter precision and uniqueidentifier precision is same.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not aware of parameter precision and uniqueidentifier precision concepts. But I will look into that, thanks.

Comment: just to make clear, if you are using nvarchar(20) for one variable/column, just make sure the other is also nvarchar(20), not less than 20 precision.